# Bootstrap 3 Carousel works locally but won't slide on Server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this for the html

```
   <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x315" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Caption Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x315" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Caption Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x315" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Caption Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div> <!-- Carousel -->
```

I've added the hosted jquery and local bootstrap.js as below to the head of the html file

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

After the carousel didnt work, I moved the jquery reference to the bottom of the html page to see if it would load since html loads from top to bottom but still no luck. Any ideas on how I can get this to work?I'm new to JQuery so please kindly be descriptive.

Comment: bootstrap carousel works without initialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I added the script sources and it worked. I'm guessing there's something wrong with my local bootstrap.js

Comment: If the problem is with the bootstrap js file then why it is working locally?

Answer (score 1):

Check if jquery

```
if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {

alert("jQuery library is loaded!");
```

}else{

```
alert("jQuery library is not found!");
```

}

and also check in chrome  hit f12 for developer mode and check under sources if jquery and boostrap are properly loaded. Check console tab if some errors occurred

Comment: I didn't find any errors related to the carousel.Just a couple related to my Glyphicons.